# Why is component not having props?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-redux

One of my component has no props and I dont know why?

I have a `MapView` component that returns the `CreatePlace` component. However, when I call the MapView component and then want to access the props of `CreatePlace`, the object is empty. The interesting thing is, when I call `CreatePlace` directly in App.js , it works, but when I call it via my MapView component, there are no props. I have been trying to sort this out for quite a while now and appreciate any clarification.

```
export default function MapView (props) {

  return (
    <Fragment>     
      <CreatePlace/>
    </Fragment>
  )

}
```

```
export class CreatePlace extends Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
    }

    render() {
        console.log(this.props) // returns empty object
        return(
            "Test"
            )
    }
}

const mapStateToProps = state => ({
    places: state.place
});

export default connect(
    mapStateToProps,
    {addPlace}
)(CreatePlace);
```

I expect such a return so I can access my addPlace function or anything else in my redux store.

```
// working console.log when calling CreatePlace in my App.js
{places: {…}, addPlace: ƒ}
addPlace: ƒ ()
places: {place: {…}}
__proto__: Object

// not working console.log when calling CreatePlace in my MapView
{}
__proto__: Object
```

Comment: `<CreatePlace/>` and `const mapStateToProps = state => ({});` mean you're not passing any props in. What are you expecting?

Comment: because you didn't pass any props

Comment: Tell us what you expect

Comment: I added my expected outcome.

Comment: As far as i can see it i am unable to access my redux store when calling 'CreatePlace' from my 'MapView' component.

Answer (score 0):

In `mapStateToProps` you need to `return object` with some values. You have returned an empty object. And `this.props` object is empty and `that's why you are getting an empty object` ;)
If your `reducer` is returning some state, add that to the variable in the object and then access that state.

For Example, if your reducer returns `comments` array. You need to do:

```
const mapStateToProps = state => ({
   comments:state.comments
});
```

Comment: Hi Imran thanks for your answer. I added some objects to return in my mapStateToProps (see my updated question). However the problem remains.

Comment: let me see :) NP

Comment: See my friend. Our CreatePlace Component has to connect to the Store to get data from. Right. We actually deal with reducers after all the boiler plate code is set up, Initial Provider and all such stuff. Reducers function should return a state and we can then access that state. If you could put your code on codesandbox, add all the dependencies there, a